# standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error" when build tiktokapi:latest

Tags: python, linux, docker, api

trying to build

> docker build . -t tiktokapi:latest and get this error message:

> Step 2/4 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip
> ---> Running in e46c478aadab
> standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"

I am new to doker so how can I fix this.

Comment: Could be a mismatch between the image and the host architecture.

Comment: okey that explain something Is a way I can fix it.Thanx. my pc is i368 Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You have not provided sufficient data to make more than a guess.